# I'm trying to install SonarQube 5.1 but when i try to run the server the wrapper stops. I already installed SonarQube as service but it didn't work

Tags: sonarqube

I already installed SonarQube as a service, but it immediately stops. So i'm trying to do it by the CMD but the wrapper stops.

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights         Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2015.05.07 12:17:44 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch pro
cess[search]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1
G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseCon
cMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupanc
yOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Sonar\sonarqube-5.1\te
mp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer     C:\Users\temp
late\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process9133461916836706948properties
jvm 1    | 2015.05.07 12:17:55 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
jvm 1    | 2015.05.07 12:17:55 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch pro
cess[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.e
ncoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=fal
se -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.pref
erIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Sonar\sonarqube-5.1\temp -cp ./lib/common/*
;./lib/server/*;C:\Sonar\sonarqube-5.1\lib\jdbc\mysql\mysql-connector-java-5.1.3
4.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\template\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-pro
cess4736183197170270861properties
jvm 1    | 2015.05.07 12:18:19 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread]     Process[searc
h] is stopping
jvm 1    | 2015.05.07 12:18:20 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread]         Process[searc
h] is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Check logs in $SQ_HOME/logs/sonar.log, this should tell you why it stops.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a problem of rights on the service: http://qualilogy.com/en/migrate-sonarqube-tomcat-to-windows-service/

Hope it helps.